# displaying listview info into different textviews android

Tags: android, textview

I want to display each item that is clicked into a different textView. I have each click displaying in the same textView now but i would like on each click for the data to be displayed in a new textView. Any Ideas? here is what i have so far:

```
        ExercisesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            private String result;
            TextView Exercise1TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Exercise1TextView);
            TextView Exercise2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Exercise2TextView);


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String Exercise = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                result = (Exercise1TextView.getText().toString() + "\n" + Exercise);
                Exercise1TextView.setText(result);

            }


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is very simple, you will need to create new TextViews dynamically and setText to them. This is how you should proceed. Add a linearlayout in your main layout above or below your listview where ever you desire, just like below.

```
    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        />
```

In your Activity initialize this linearlayout

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            private LinearLayout mainLayout;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(....);
                   setContentView(....);
                   this.mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
            }
    }
```

Now in your onItemClick do like this.

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setText(result);
    mainLayout.addView(tv, params);
```

Comment: does it have to be Linear Layout? i already have a relative layout set up. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3091082 You can add whatever layout you desire, the above code will work fine. Every layout has its addView method. But LayoutParams will differ. Instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams you will need RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of TextViews like that:

```
View[] myViews = {textView1, textView2, ....};
```

And call them inside onItemClick()

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

     k = myViews.length < i ? myViews.length -1 : i; //or use your logic
     String Exercise = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
     result = (Exercise1TextView.getText().toString() + "\n" + Exercise);
     myViews[k].setText(result);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand what you are trying to do but I don't fully understand this line, k = myViews.length < i = myViews.length -1 : i; .  Could you explain please?

Comment: "i" implies your position in the listview. I gave this for an example you should use your logic there. And if you wanna wonder what I did there, i used clicked item's position and called the myViews[clicked item position]. In case your view count is smaller than list items than it calls the myViews[last item]. It is shortened version of if else condition. btw i corrected mistakes in my answer. look at it again.